# Best practices regarding React and its versions with various ways to accomplish the same goal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, version, jsx

As far as I am concerned, functional components and hooks are the way to go in React, since they are more modern. However, I am surprised to see that many React references (including the official Docs themselves) still use class-based components and do not promote these new features that are supposedly better. Plus, I noticed people looking into learning React are in two minds about which of these two ways to go. So, why are the docs and other accepted examples still using older tools in React? Can one accomplish things with the old version that are still impossible with the new one?

Comment: Neither is better. It is just that there are two ways to create a component in React - Class and Function. You may choose to use one of these, or maybe both in a project. It is mostly your choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish everything with both class and functional components. There is no right or wrong.

If you understand functional programming paradigm and its benefits then go with functional components.
Otherwise you can technically achieve anything with class components as well.